# Postgres updatable View

Tags: database, postgresql, view

in my application I created a view in order to let the users fill the data in relative tables. I've made view updatable by using a trigger function.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO evento_investimento (data, ora, rilevatore_id, strada_id, chilometro_strada,
latitudine, longitudine, barriera_sinistra, barriera_destra, vegetazione_primi_metri, sezione_trasversale,
curvilinearità, uso_suolo_prevalente_50m_destra, uso_suolo_prevalente_50m_sinistra, specie_id, stato_specie_id, sesso_id, classe_id)

VALUES (NEW.data,NEW.ora,
(SELECT rilevatore_id FROM rilevatore WHERE rilevatore.nome_cognome = NEW.nome_cognome),
(SELECT strada_id FROM strada WHERE strada.nome_strada = NEW.nome_strada),
NEW.chilometro_strada, NEW.latitudine, NEW.longitudine, NEW.barriera_sinistra, NEW.barriera_destra, NEW.vegetazione_primi_metri,
NEW.sezione_trasversale, NEW.curvilinearità, NEW.uso_suolo_prevalente_50m_destra, NEW.uso_suolo_prevalente_50m_sinistra,
(SELECT specie_id FROM specie WHERE specie.nome_comune = NEW.nome_comune),
(SELECT stato_specie_id FROM stato_specie WHERE stato_specie.stato = NEW.stato),
(SELECT sesso_id FROM sesso WHERE sesso.sesso_specie = NEW.sesso_specie),
(SELECT classe_id FROM classe_eta WHERE classe_eta.classe_eta = NEW.classe_eta)
);

if not exists(select * from rilevatore where rilevatore.nome_cognome=new.nome_cognome) then
INSERT INTO rilevatore (nome_cognome, telefono, email, ente_appartenenza)
VALUES (NEW.nome_cognome, NEW.telefono, NEW.email, NEW.ente_appartenenza);
end if;

if not exists(select * from specie where specie.nome_comune=new.nome_comune) then
INSERT INTO specie (nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES (NEW.nome_comune, NEW.nome_scientifico);
end if;

if not exists(select * from strada where strada.nome_strada=new.nome_strada) then
INSERT INTO strada (nome_strada)
VALUES (NEW.nome_strada);
end if;

if not exists(select * from sesso where sesso.sesso_specie=new.sesso_specie) then
INSERT INTO sesso (sesso_specie)
VALUES (NEW.sesso_specie);
end if;

if not exists(select * from stato_specie where stato_specie.stato=new.stato) then
INSERT INTO stato_specie (stato)
VALUES (NEW.stato);
end if;

if not exists(select * from classe_eta where classe_eta.classe_eta=classe_eta) then
INSERT INTO classe_eta (classe_eta)
VALUES (NEW.classe_eta);
end if;

RETURN NEW;
END;
```

While the function works fine in filling the data, the view doesn't update automatically, that is new data doesn't appear in the view. How can i solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]**

Actually, the view works fine. The issue concerns the evento_investimento table. If a new value is added to the view, i.e. a new specie.nome_comune that doesn't exist in the specie table, the function correctly update the specie table but the specie_id in the evento_investimento table doesn't appear. As a consequence the view won't update.

Here a simplified example.

create table specie

```
CREATE TABLE specie
(
specie_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
nome_comune TEXT UNIQUE,
nome_scientifico TEXT UNIQUE
);
```

fill the table with some values:

```
insert into specie
(nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
values
('lupo', 'Canis lupus'),
('lontra', 'Lutra lutra');
```

create table rilevatore

```
CREATE TABLE rilevatore
        (
        rilevatore_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
        nome_cognome TEXT
        );
```

fill the table with some values:

```
insert into rilevatore
(nome_cognome)
values
('mario'),
('luca');
```

create table evento_investimento

```
CREATE TABLE evento_investimento
    (
    evento_id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    data DATE,
    ora TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    rilevatore_id INT REFERENCES rilevatore (rilevatore_id),
    specie_id INT REFERENCES specie(specie_id)
    );
```

Let fill some data in evento_investimento

```
insert into evento_investimento
(data, ora, rilevatore_id, specie_id)
values
('2019-12-31', '16:54:00',1,1)
```

Create a view to fill the data

```
CREATE VIEW inserimento_dati_vista AS
SELECT row_number() OVER ()::integer AS gid,
evento_investimento.ora,
evento_investimento.data,
rilevatore.nome_cognome,
specie.nome_comune,
specie.nome_scientifico
FROM evento_investimento
JOIN specie ON evento_investimento.specie_id = specie.specie_id
JOIN rilevatore ON evento_investimento.rilevatore_id = rilevatore.rilevatore_id;
```

Now create the trigger function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inserimento_dati_fun_2() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO evento_investimento (data, ora, rilevatore_id, specie_id)
VALUES (NEW.data,NEW.ora,
(SELECT rilevatore_id FROM rilevatore WHERE rilevatore.nome_cognome = NEW.nome_cognome),
(SELECT specie_id FROM specie WHERE specie.nome_comune = NEW.nome_comune)
);
if not exists(select * from rilevatore where rilevatore.nome_cognome=new.nome_cognome) then
INSERT INTO rilevatore (nome_cognome)
VALUES (NEW.nome_cognome);
end if;
if not exists(select * from specie where specie.nome_comune=new.nome_comune) then
INSERT INTO specie (nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES (NEW.nome_comune, NEW.nome_scientifico);
end if;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger inserimento_dati_fun_trg 
    instead of insert on inserimento_dati_vista for each row EXECUTE procedure inserimento_dati_fun_2();
```

Running this code give me correct results:

```
INSERT INTO inserimento_dati_vista
(data, ora, nome_cognome, nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES
('2020-01-01', '16:54:00','mario', 'lupo', 'Canis lupus'),
('2020-01-02', '13:54:00','luca', 'lontra', 'Lutra lutra')
```

When I insert a new nome_cognome or nome_comune

```
INSERT INTO inserimento _dati_vista
(data, ora, nome_cognome, nome_comune, nome_scientifico)
VALUES
('2020-01-01', '16:54:00','piero', 'orso', 'Ursus arctos')
```

the tables rilevatore and specie correctly update but evento_investimento doesn't.

Comment: Please provide a simple reproducible test case including table and view definitions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When function works with filling data in tables and only views are problem, you have to recreate views after insert, they dont update automatically.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: That's wrong. A view is just a `SELECT` statement with a name. Whenever you select from the view, you select from the underlying tables. Look at the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: Actually, the view works fine. The issue concerns the evento_investimento table. If a new value is added to the view, i.e. a new specie.nome_comune that doesn't exist in the specie table, the function correctly update the specie table but the specie_id in the evento_investimento table doesn't appear. As a consequence the view won't update.

Comment: Contrary to initial appearance both @efysis and LaurenzeAlbe are correct. The reason you see what you do is that you populated your display via a select from the view. However, updating does NOT re-execute that select, so it's the display that is not updated. You need to refresh the display.